# How to give Hardcoded values to Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This is my Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Test> test = new Dictionary<string, Test>();
```

In the Test, i am having Id,Name,Score. I want to fill these properties with hard coded values.(More than one count).

How to give static values to Dictionary

Whether i should give like this...

```
Dictionary<string, Test> test= new Dictionary<string, Test>();
Groups groups = new Groups();
groups.Id = "1";
groups.Name = "Name";
groups.Description = "Desc";
test.Add(groups.Id, groups);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the collection initialiser syntax in C#3 & 4:

```
var data = new Dictionary<String,Object> {
  { "Foo", "Bax" },
  { "Bar", new DateTime(2010,10,10) },
  { "Xyzzy", 42 }
};
```

---

*Additional*: The updated question code:

```
Dictionary<string, Test> test= new Dictionary<string, Test>();
Groups groups = new Groups();
groups.Id = "1";
groups.Name = "Name";
groups.Description = "Desc";
test.Add(groups.Id, groups);
```

can be re-written as a single expression (also noting the value type seems to be `Groups`, and showing how to add multiple key-value pairs):

```
Dictionary<string, Test> test= new Dictionary<string, Groups> {
  {
    "1", new Groups {
      Id = "1",
      Name = "Name",
      Description = "Desc"
    }
  }, {
    "2", new Groups {
      Id = "2",
      Name = "Another Name",
      Description = "Something        }
  }
};
```

Comment: Whether i should give like this........Dictionary<string, Test> test= new Dictionary<string, Test>();
            var Data = new Dictionary<string, Test>
            {
                {1,"A","A"},
                {2,"B","B"},
            };

Comment: @RobinHood: No that won't work. First member of the inner braces is the key and the second member is the value. The second member of each pair needs to be able to initialise a `Test`, which depends on the definition of `Test`. The simplest way is to call a constructor. A literal would also work with an appropriate implicit conversion defined.